# SQL Server - OVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen día a todos.

Estoy usando OVER para realizar una suma acumulada, pero tengo el problema que si encuentra 2 valores iguales no los esta sumando sino hasta que encuentra el valor siguiente.

Podrían ayudarme para validar si tengo algo incorecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Comparte el código completo que estás ejecutando como texto y no como imagen. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que la función de ventana sólo suma cuando hay cambios en el criterio de ordenamiento. Para dicho problema, la solución es tan simple como agregar más columnas a dicho criterio para hacerlo único.

Por ejemplo a tu línea:

```
cast(sum(Pareto) over(order by [Total Pacientes] desc)
  as decimal(36, 2)) as [Acumulado]
```

Podrías agregarle `IdPersonal` para forzar un ordenamiento único. Quedaría como:

```
cast(sum(Pareto) over(order by [Total Pacientes] desc, IdPersonal) 
  as decimal(36, 2)) as [Acumulado]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias con esto se soluciono todo...!!!

Comment: @wltr07 Si funciona, acepta la respuesta.