# Sumar una columna en SQL pero ver el proceso de la suma

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

Tengo el siguiente problema, necesito sumar totales pero que se vea en una columa el incremento de este total,
Por ejemplo

[image: Id total sumatotal 3 15 15 6 8 24 7 7 31]

Así sucesivamente, estoy trabajando el SQL server

Comment: [¿Suma acumulada?](/search?q=suma+acumulada+[sql-server])

Comment: En el SQL convencional te entrega la suma total de una columna, yo lo que quiero es que en cada renglon me muestre como va incrementando esa suma, si es posible sin la necesidad de ocupar un GROUP BY

Comment: Por eso, suma acumulada. Dale clic al enlace de mi comentario anterior.

Comment: ¿Cual manejador de base de datos estás utilizando? La sintaxis puede variar de un producto a otro.

Comment: Gracias padaleiana encontro la respueta en este post. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/346976/sql-server-over